# Prove that if $a_n$ is a non-negative sequence, lim $a_n$ = 0 $\implies$ lim $\sqrt{a_n}$ =0

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

The book I am using for my Advance Calculus course is Introduction to Analysis by Arthur Mattuck.

Prove that if $a_n$ is a non-negative sequence, lim $a_n$ = 0 $\implies$ lim $\sqrt{a_n}$ =0

This is my rough proof to this question. I was wondering if anybody can look over it and see if I made a mistake or if there is a simpler way of doing this problem. I want to thank you ahead of time it is greatly appreciated.So lets begin:

Proof:

[image]

Comment: Your line "...therefore (1) becomes ..." is false. If the limit of the numerator and denominator are both 0, you can't directly deduce what the limit is. Think of $a_n = \frac{1}{2^n}$ for example. Anyway, this method is much too fancy. Just use a regular $\epsilon$ proof.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Then by assumption (convergence) there is some $N \geq 1$ such that
$a_{n} < \varepsilon^{2}$ for all $n \geq N$. But by assumption again (nonnegativity) we have $\sqrt{a_{n}} < \varepsilon$ for all $n \geq N$.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is false, because you may have $(a_n)$ going to $0$ without having $((a_n)^{\frac{1}{n}})$ going to $0$.

Example :

$$a_n=\frac{1}{n} $$

Clearly $(a_n)$ goes to $0$ but $a_n^{\frac{1}{n}}=e^{-\frac{1}{n}log(n)}$ now $-\frac{1}{n}log(n)$ goes to $0$ at infinity so that $(a_n^{\frac{1}{n}})$ converges to $1$.

Now, to show your property, use the fact that :

$$\sqrt{a_n}=e^{\frac{1}{2}log(a_n)} $$